# Moderate Facebook Comments Plugin

Tags: facebook, social-networking

I have a site where users share documents, and I set a Facebook comment box for each document, with different URL for separate comments (more than 200k!).

What it's the easiest way to moderate comments without enter in each document URL? As I can read, I need a Facebook App ID, but I can't find the way to get it, and also I don't need a full facebook app, I only want moderation. It's possible to set the admin ID in the plugin to a fan page and moderate all from them?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My dear you need to have an APP ID. While getting the process of APP ID (making an application in facebook developers) you just need to enter your email address as developer of facebook. Then just put facebook comment box plugin and you will see the plugin shows a link "Administer Comment" below the post button. Click on that button you will see a small window where you can set your moderator.
This is qutite simple.

Comment: I try to do this, but I get an error when enter in http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php

Comment: Strage error. From how many days your are getting this problem?

Comment: Solved: for create an APP ID you first need to use the Facebook APP Developer: https://www.facebook.com/developers/

Comment: @javier Marin. If my answer has helped you a little bit or not?

Answer (score 0):

you can moderate facebook comment in Comments Evolved for WordPress plugin, we just need to create facebook app id, and have to edit wordpress header.php.

I had just shared a post on this you can refer it...

[Enable Comments Evolved Pluging for Moderate Facebook Comment in WordPress.](http://www.tipsviablogging.com/moderate-facebook-comment-evolved-wordpress/)